# NASM calculates label position wrongly

Tags: assembly, dos, nasm, portable-executable

I use NASM to create a small PE executable and I have the MZ header, the DOS stub program and the PE header. Unfortunately and suddenly I see that NASM cannot calculate the relative position of one of the labels and is unable to save the correct PE header address. My code looks like this:

```
%macro orgup 2
    org (((%1+(%2-1))/%2)*%2) 
%endmacro

DOS_HEADER:
    dw "MZ"
    dw PE_HEADER - DOS_HEADER
    dw 1
    dw 0
    dw 4
    dw 0
    dw 65535
    dw 0
    dw 0x00B8
    dw 0
    dw 0
    dw 0
    dw 0x0040
    dw 0
    dq 0
    dw 0
    dw 0
    times 20 db 0
    dd PE_HEADER  ; This should be 80 00 but instead it is 80 10

DOS_PROGRAM:
    ; This is where I have my little DOS program

PE_HEADER: ; In the binary it starts at 0x8000
    db "PE", 0, 0
    ; And so on ...

OPTIONAL_HEADER:
    dw 0x010B
    ; And so on ...

TEXT_SECTION_HEADER:
    db ".text" ,0 ,0 ,0
    ; And so on ...

TEXT_SECTION_HEADER:
    db ".bss" ,0 ,0 ,0
    ; And so on ...

use32  

align           512
rawstart:
    orgup $-$$, 4096 ; THIS IS WHAT PRODUCES THE PROBLEM.
; And so on
```

So, when the `orgup` macro is there, the address of `PE_HEADER` is *1080h* (which is related somehow with the second argument of `orgup`). If I comment that line, the address is *80h* (correct). So, it looks like NASM considers the code before `use32` part of the `.text` section or something. How could I specify that everything before `rawstart` must calculated from origin 0, in 16 bits?

Comment: `MZ` header: either `db "MZ"` or `dw "ZM"`, but not `dw "MZ"`.

Comment: Nasm will accept only one `org` directive. Consider creating a new `section` with a `vstart=` attribute to get the same effect. See the Friendly Manual for details.

Comment: Thanks. Using section with vstart was the real solution